# fill out protocol relative URLs via search-and-replace in HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, http, url, replace

I have a web application that uses protocol-relavtive URLs for everything to be as dynamic as possible, the problem is that in certain cases these dont work, for example as redirect URLs for 3rd party auth, so the question is there some way I can point at a redirect url which is in the HTML code referenced as a `data-redirect-url="//abc.com/auth.php"` attribute inside an HTML `<button>` and prepend http/https to it depending on the active protocol?

by the way, I know that it's better to serve content only over HTTPS and that people might not want to use the these URLs anymore, but I want to be dynamic, because e.g. with a localhost test HTTPS REALLY isnt needed.

---

long story short.
if HTTP

replace
(php-regex) `data-redirect-url="//(.+?)"`

with
(php-regex) `data-redirect-url="http://$1"`

if HTTPS,

instead use
(php-regex) `data-redirect-url="https://$1"`

I am very bad with js (in fact I avoid it when I can) so try to keep the code understandable and not too complex if possible.

Comment: If these do not work in redirects in a browser (which?): raise a bug report.

Comment: this isnt for a browser redirect, but it is the so-called redirect URL that a 3rd party authorization provider gets to put the user back to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `location.protocol` which return the protocol of the current URL. `http:` or `https:`

Per your comment, you have a button :

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info" data-redirect-url="//somedynamicallygeneratedurl">
```

To change the `data-redirect-url`, use:

```
var urlButtons  = document.querySelectorAll('.btn[data-redirect-url]');

for(var _index = 0; _index < urlButtons.length; _index++) {
  var btn = urlButtons[_index];
  btn.setAttribute('data-redirect-url', location.protocol+btn.getAttribute('data-redirect-url'));

  console.log(btn.getAttribute('data-redirect-url'));
}
```

Comment: looks nice, and it's small too (one of my greatest js problems is the huge ajax script that tend to fail over mobile internet) I'll try it soon.

Comment: but that data-redirect URL is actually a variable in js?
because it's at leasat in the code an atribute of an html element

Comment: The way you are writing is puts it in a variable...this will not work if you put in in the html

Comment: well I actually need to replace HTML code for that because it's inside a `<button>`

Comment: `data-redirect-url` is your javascript variable. I changed it to `var url` to be more clear.

Comment: well too bad I need to change a bit of HTML code, so too bad.

Comment: Post your html code and which element you want to change.

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info" data-redirect-url="//somedynamicallygeneratedurl">` (I ommited some other attributes for simiplicity)
I provided at the question some PHP-style regex which could be used for a simple search and replace right in the code and it would be great just to provide a regex search and replace in the code based on that.

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: @Maxali You somewhat stole my answer :/

Comment: How my answer becomes even near to yours? See the comments. I changed the answer according to @My1 's question. You are also using jQuery?

Comment: @Maxali I knew what he meant and provided that snippet for him. After that you came with a somewhat same answer...But ill let it go. Let both upvote since they are both correct :)

Comment: but after some testing this answer works better than the one from kbninja, maybe jquery comes in too late before the js from clef grabs the URL, because in the code I see the result but the script from them seems not to have noticed...
I gave you both a vote since both solutions look pretty solid and kbninja's one almost worked, albeit almost. also the code is not too large and easy to understand. kudos, both of you

Answer (score 2):

I used some jQuery for this solution, but this might do the trick
It changes your HTML when its ready

The only thing you have to do is paste this in your page

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var el = $('[data-redirect-url]')
    el.each(function(el){
        var i = $(this).attr('data-redirect-url');
        $(this).attr('data-redirect-url', location.protocol+i)
    });
});
```

Comment: probably this thing comes in a bit late (maybe jquery takes too long to load, whatever it might be) but the script from clef seems to get the URL before your script intervenes, but the result is there.